# Maximum size of imageviews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the layout you see on the picture. Cells for each ImageView are set to be equally sized by width and height. Scale type of images are "fitXY". Currently all images resize depending on screen size and often are upscaled.

I want to achieve the following behavior:
set maxSize - maximum width and height of an image. When cells are smaller than maxSize ImageView behave just like with "fitXY", but if cells are bigger than maxSize then images won't upscale further. I don't want to have images for different DPIs, but to resize big icons on the fly.

As I understand there should be different maxSize values for different screen sizes and resolutions.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_www"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:padding="40dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_fb"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="40dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_twitter"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:padding="40dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_youtube"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:padding="40dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml here.
And yes,Try to add dimensions dynamically for different size and dps of screens.

Comment: added xml, I can set maximum sizes for ImageViews via xml for some reasons, even if layout_width and layout_height are set to wrap_content

Comment: Have you tried android:maxWidth ?

Comment: yes, I tried it, this doesn't work. images upscale just as before

Comment: Are you setting static values in xml?
Or from dimes.xml file dynamically?As per Device resolution and density?

Comment: these are static values, they work good for most resolutions and densities, the only problem is the maximum size. I'm thinking, maybe create a custom ImageView overriding dimensions setting, this might work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and change 'android:scaleType="center"' to `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_www"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

**EDIT**
your `android:maxHeight` isn't working because by giving `layout_height` as 0dp and `layout_weight` as 1, you are giving a specific height value to the view. `max_height` and `max_width` only works in case your don't have a specific value of height and width for a view. Put `wrap_content` as the `layout_height` and remove `layout_weight`. Similarly by giving `layout_width` as `match_parent`, you are defining a specific value for the height of the view. replace `match_parent` with `wrap_content` and it will work.

Comment: than `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` will do

Comment: the problem is that I can't set the maximum size of images

Comment: whatever you give as `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` are the max width and max height for that view

Comment: they are "exact" dimensions of the view, not maximum and furthermore the proportions of the layout will be lost in this case